# Facebook app submission

Tags: android, ios, facebook, publish-actions

I have submitted one of my iOS apps in Facebook for "publish_actions" permission, Facebook has approved. So, users could able to post the message, photo or video by using my iOS app.

Now, I have developed the same app in Android platform and associated to the same Facebook App ID.

I am sure that we cannot submit the app for "publish_actions" since it is already approved for that Facebook App ID.
So, what shall we do in this case?

Shall I just add Android platform in Facebook and submit the app in Google Play?

Does users have any issue in sharing the content in future?

Could anyone suggest what can I do to take my Android app go forward with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add the platform and submit it to Google Play.

Permissions are given for an App and not for a particular platform.

Thanks